# Xampp is not recognized VirtualHost after few attempts?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I had installed xampp few years ago. But now I have a little problem with the configuration of the vhost.

I have 4 different pages in my server, the apache is running with the port 80. So my configuration to the vhost is as following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/munkys
    ServerName www.munkys.com.co
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/munkys">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/flinda
    ServerName www.flinda.com.co
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/flinda">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/pluxpc
    ServerName www.pluxpc.com.co
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/pluxpc">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/conradoarte
    ServerName www.conrado-arte.com.co
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/paginasweb/conradoarte">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is the following:

When I tried to join to my website, www.conradoarte.com.co, the page is loading outside the local network but after a few minutes or attempts the dns is lost, but if I join to the website inside my local network the page is up. After reload the page from my local network I can see again the page outside the local network.

I don't know what is the real problem.